# Different decode performance in two similar H.264 videos

Tags: encoding, h.264, performance

I have two, at first glance very similar [mp4 files](https://mega.nz/folder/Z0VGHbaQ#VqTrfNIkMqYnK2H5vyapnA) (A & B), each of them created by different capture software.

| File | Captured using | codec | resolution | fps | bitrate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A.mp4 | Elgato 4K Capture Utility | h.264 | 2560x1440 | 60 | 106Mb/s |
| B.mp4 | Xsplit Broadcaster | h.264 | 2560x1440 | 60 | 128Mb/s |

I noticed that scrubbing video A is very smooth while scrubbing video B is extremely choppy.

[This video](https://youtube.com/watch?v=SsMr8u9K4B0) illustrates the difference. Note that althought for demonstration purpose I've used DaVinci Resolve software, the same scrubbing performance is present in other programs e.g. VLC Player.

I would like to understand what is causing this difference in scrubbing performance. Looking at task manager graphs, it seems like video B is more complex to decode but I have no idea why.

This is what I got using MediaInfo
[image: Media info]

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The difference in scrubbing performance comes from different [GOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_pictures) in those two videos. The video which played smoothly had GOP=(N, M)=(15, 1).

So for people who'll encounter this issue in videos produced by their capture software: to fix it set keyframe interval to low value e.g. 30 frames (0.5sec)

It's also possible to convert existing videos using ffmpeg in order to add more keyframes e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 16 -preset faster -g 15 output.mp4
```

where `-g 15` sets keyframe every 15 frames